# How to properly work with wamp locally?

Tags: wampserver

I was working on my new project using wamp.
 Everything was fine until I uploaded the files to my real server (hostgator), where I already have another website hosted. 
I put the files of my new project in a subfolder so that it could work like a test environment. 
After that, whenever I try to open the home page of my new project in wamp I'm redirected to the page in my real webserver.
 I only want to work locally. What can I do to fix it?
 All I want is to use wamp locally to continue developing the new website.

Comment: So you modified some code/parameter before copying code to the live server?

Comment: No, man. In fact I'm giving up wamp. That kind of thing should not happen. I'm tired of trying to make it work.

Comment: Thats will be because you have HARD CODED `localhost` somewhere in the code you moved to the LIVE server. When you click on that link or redirect to that it will look on your `local` machine and in your case find something _A bad workman always blames his tools_